# the_field() function puts value in the wrong position

Tags: php, wordpress, function, advanced-custom-fields

so i was trying to get the value of a custom field I created. Basically I'd like to populate a gravityforms shortcode (inside the loop) in my template with a dynamically given ID through a custom field in wordpress. I'm using the acf get_field function and I don't really understand what's going wrong. In this case the gravityform has the ID '3'.

Here's my approach:

```
echo do_shortcode('[gravityforms id="'.the_field('gf-for-events').'" title="false" description="false" ajax="true"]');
```

Now the result I get is this:

```
3
Oops! We could not locate your form.
```

The ID that gets output is indeed the right one, but for some reason it is output in the wrong position. To further test this I tried this:

```
$test = the_field('gf-for-events');
echo ('[gravityforms id="'.$test.'" title="false" description="false" ajax="true"]');
```

here's the output:

```
3[gravityforms id="" title="false" description="false" ajax="true"]
```

I know it has to do with the_field function since when hardcoding the ID it gets put out in the right way.

```
$test = 3;
echo ('[gravityforms id="'.$test.'" title="false" description="false" ajax="true"]');
```

```
[gravityforms id="3" title="false" description="false" ajax="true"]
```

I'd like to understand what's going wrong here, is there anything I have missed? Is there another approach to get_field() that I can use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `the_field()` method will output the value right away. When you use `get_field()` instead, it will be returned as a return value, so you can assign it to a variable.

Then you can use the value anywhere in your code:

```
$value = get_field('gf-for-events');
if ( $value ) {
  echo '[gravityforms id="' . $value . '" title="false" description="false" ajax="true"]';
}
```

This should output (in case the return value is indeed `3`):

```
[gravityforms id="3" title="false" description="false" ajax="true"]
```

This is also described in the documentation of [`the_field()`](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/the_field/) and [`get_field()`](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/get_field/) respectively:

> **the_field():** Displays the value of a specific field.
>
> **get_field():** Returns the value of a specific field.

Comment: Awesome that worked thanks! In the documentation of the_field() it is stated at the beginning that it is the same function as get_field(). That's why I didn't look further into get_field.

Comment: Read more carefully, the documentation states that it is the same as `echo get_field()`. The keyword `echo` makes a big difference here, as you noticed.