# PHP echo not outputting html tags

Tags: php, html, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, acfpro

I'm trying to output content from an [Advanced Custom Fields (ACF)](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com) in my wordpress theme. At the moment though, all I'm getting is the plain text content from the ACF inside double quotation marks, not inside the `div` and `h1` tags.

The code is copied from another theme I made where it worked, which makes me think something is interfering with it somewhere?

```
<?php $process_title = the_sub_field('process_title'); ?>

<?php if(!empty($process_title)) : ?>
    <div class="process-title">
        <h1 class="process-heading">
            <?php echo $process_title; ?>
        </h1>
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: `the_sub_field()` doesn't return the value, it outputs the contents straight away. You should use `get_the_sub_field()` if you want it to return the data instead. This is a general naming convention in WordPress. `the_something()` = output and `get_the_something()` = returns the value instead.

Comment: or per @M.Eriksson comments `the_sub_field('process_title')` could be used in place of `echo $process_title`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [the\_field() function puts value in the wrong position](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63811084/the-field-function-puts-value-in-the-wrong-position)

Comment: Thanks @M.Eriksson you suggestion worked once I'd figured out hte typo in it, you meant get_sub_field not get_the_sub_field

Comment: @Jono - Yes, that's correct :-)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @M.Eriksson, the correct code should be:

```
<?php $process_title = get_sub_field('process_title'); ?>
<?php if(!empty($process_title)) : ?>
    <div class="process-title">
        <h1 class="process-heading">
            <?php echo $process_title; ?>
        </h1>
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```